# pythonw.exe has stopped working when running QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I copied a simple PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFileDialog code from web, but I found 
this code didn't work in my device, I'm not sure if something are incompatible in my environment .

my python version : Python3.4.  32bit
   PyQt version   : PyQt5.5  32bit

The error is :
**"pythonw.exe has stopped working when running QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory"**

please see below screen shot and code
[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog,QFileDialog
from os.path import expanduser
import sys
import design 

class ExampleApp(QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(ExampleApp, self).__init__()

          self.setupUi(self)
          self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

      def browse_folder(self):
           self.listWidget.clear()
           directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                       "Pick a folder")
           if directory: 
               for file_name in os.listdir(directory): 
                  self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)   
def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)   
   form = ExampleApp()
   form.show()
   app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Is the dialog shown before the error occurs? What happens if you set a start directory (i.e. as a third argument to `getExistingDirectory`)? Do any of the other dialogs work (e.g. `getOpenFileName`)?

Comment: no any error occurs before the dialog shown.  and same error happen to run getOpenFileName or give third argument to getExistsingDirectory

Comment: There is no real error: the dialog is just very, very slow to open, which is why Windows shows that useless message. A search on `qfiledfialog windows slow` brings up lots of hits, so it seems to be a fairly common problem on Windows. Try setting the fourth agrument to `QFileDialog.DontUseCustomDirectoryIcons` or `QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog`.